Is EDR agents good to install on a fleet of Raspberry pi
I recently discover the existence of EDR and thought of installing one on a "fleet" of raspberry pi to manage potentials intrusion or weird behavior via a dashboard or something.
Is that possible and / or a good idea ? If yes, is there any open-source software or free one that can do that ?
Thanks for your time
